# Failed to locate resource: lwjgl32.dll

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I have a problem with compilling my application.
I use Eclipse Luna (Also, try in Neon, Mars.(1|2)), and LWJGL 3 (.0.0 Build 90 ( Also try .0.1 build 8 ))
And with starting i get this error (via "-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true"):

```
[LWJGL] Version: 3.0.0 build 90
[LWJGL]      OS: Windows XP v5.1
[LWJGL]     JRE: 1.8.0_91 x86
[LWJGL]     JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM v25.91-b15 by Oracle Corporation
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl32
[LWJGL]     Using SharedLibraryLoader...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to extract the LWJGL shared library
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:41)
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:58)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:76)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:43)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:17)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:562)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.init(Main.java:35)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.run(Main.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to locate resource: lwjgl32.dll
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:80)
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:39)
... 9 more
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
    b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\workspace_luna_java\JGame\native\lwjgl32.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:110)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystemRelative(Library.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:71)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:43)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:17)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:562)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.init(Main.java:35)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.run(Main.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

P.S. All paths are set.
P.P.S. Windows Xp - I use an old laptop.
P.P.P.S. "Не найдена указанная процедура" - Approximate translation: "Not found the specified procedure"

Comment: That linker error is caused by the first one. Lwjgl couldn't load the dll it needs in order to provide the function the linker is looking for. Have you double-checked to make sure the file `D:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\workspace_luna_java\JGame\native\lwjgl32.dll` actually exists?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Of course, `lwjgl32.dll` on this path exists, i know it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have `java.library.path` or `org.lwjgl.librarypath` set, LWJGL tries to extract the dll via the `SharedLibraryLoader`. This searches for dlls contained in jar files on your classpath, but because your dll isn't inside one, it won't get loaded.

So, to solve this problem you have to either set `-Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath` to the directory containing your dlls, or put them into a jar file somewhere on your classpath.